# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.graphics.Point[]

Tags: java, android, json, android-uiautomator

```
public class SendText extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    private String jsonString = "{\"A\": [[107,729],[108,728],[108,728],[108,727]," +
        "[108,727],[108,727],[108,727],[108,727],[108,727],[108,727],[108,727],[108,727],[110,724]," +
        "[114,717],[125,701],[134,685],[145,663],[157,636],[169,607],[179,583],[191,558],[196,547]," +
        "[199,540],[201,534],[202,529],[203,528],[204,525],[204,524],[204,524],[204,524],[204,524]," +
        "[204,524],[204,525],[204,530],[205,538],[207,549],[209,566],[216,602],[223,629],[229,653]," +
        "[235,671],[238,684],[241,697],[242,703],[242,707],[243,710],[243,712],[243,713],[243,713]," +
        "[243,713],[243,713],[244,713],[244,713],[244,713],[244,713],[242,709],[237,703],[230,695]," +
        "[224,684],[220,679],[215,671],[212,665],[206,658],[202,655],[200,654],[196,651],[192,648]," +
        "[189,646],[184,642],[182,641],[180,639],[179,637],[177,635],[176,634],[174,633],[173,631]," +
        "[172,630],[171,629],[170,628],[170,628],[170,627],[169,627],[169,627],[169,627],[169,627]," +
        "[169,629],[169,629]]}" ;

    public void testSendText() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {   

        JSONObject jsonObj;
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            jsonObj.getJSONArray("A");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //String line = null;

        for(int k = 0; k < jsonString.length(); k++ ){
            Vector<Point> apoints = new Vector<Point>();
            apoints.add(new Point());
            getUiDevice().swipe((Point[])apoints.toArray(), 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.swipe(apoints.toArray(new Point[apoint.size()]), 5);`

Comment: @ZouZou if instead of jsonString.length() i want to pass the actual contents of A using jsonObj...that will take array inside array...how can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Could you be more precise? Or asking a new question, that would be better :)

Comment: @ZouZou the statement "getUiDevice().swipe((Point[])apoints.toArray(), 5);" just takes the total length of the string, but i want to pass each and every coordinates so that the all of them passes through the swipe method

Comment: So for each array in the array, you want to create a new Point object and add it to the vector?

Comment: yes....so that the swipe method will draw the character "A" on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The collection interface has 2 toArray methods.  The first, Object[] toArray() returns all of the elements in a collection and stores them in an array of type Object[].  The second,  T[] toArray(T[] a) stores the collection elements in the parameter to the method if it is big enough, otherwise it allocates an array of the appropriate size via run-time reflection on a.  Your code is the equivalent of the following:
`

```
Object[] x = new Object[1];

x[0] = "Test";
System.out.println(((String[]) x)[0]); //Throws a ClassCastException
```

`
In order to fix it, just use the toArray(T[] a) version of toArray as suggested by ZouZou.